# Relating momentum fraction to rapidity in a high-energy collision

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics

It's a well-known result in particle physics that in an underlying interaction like this:

[image: splitting interaction]

assuming $p_0^-,p_{0\perp},m_0\ll p_0^+$, $m_1$ and $m_2$ are small, but $p_{1\perp}$ and $p_{2\perp}$ are large, the [rapidity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidity#In_experimental_particle_physics) ($y = \frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{p^+}{p^-}$) differences between the final particles and the initial particle are
$$\begin{align}
y_1 - y_0 &= \ln\frac{1}{\xi} \\
y_2 - y_0 &= \ln\frac{1}{1 - \xi}
\end{align}$$
perhaps neglecting some terms subleading in $E_0$.

How would I show this? Pretty much all the references I've looked at (Kovchegov and Levin, Halzen and Martin, lots of papers) seem to take it as prerequisite knowledge. I did find [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9705393) which gives a similar equation for the rapidity gap in diffractive scattering, but the derivation there relies on a nontrivial assumption about the distribution of produced particles which I don't think should be necessary.

Naturally, I've tried playing around with various kinematic equations involving rapidity, but I can't put together anything resembling the desired result.

Comment: Your picture doesn't have any momenta with a "-" superscript, so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: The minus components can be whatever they need to be, given the restriction that $p_0^-$ is small (as mentioned in the question). There *may* be some additional restriction on the minus components that is required for $y_1 - y_0$ to (approximately) equal $\ln\frac{1}{\xi}$, but I don't know what it might be. Ideally a good answer would explain that.

Comment: Sorry, stupid question, I see now that obviously $p^+$ is notation for $E+p$, $p^-$ for $E-p$, and that these are called light-cone components.

Answer (score 3):

I'll take the simple, one-dimensional case. Since $\sqrt{2} p^+ = E + p$ and $\sqrt{2} p^- = E - p$, it works out that
$$
p^- = \frac{m^2}{2p^+}
$$
So, the rapidity of a particle is
$$
y = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{p^+}{p^-} = C + \ln \frac{p^+}{m}
$$
and therefore
$$
y_1 - y_0 = - \ln \frac{1}{\xi} + \ln \frac{m_0}{m_1} \\
y_2 - y_0 = - \ln \frac{1}{1-\xi} + \ln \frac{m_0}{m_2}
$$
So, I need to re-express the log of the ratios of the masses in terms of $\xi$.
Conservation of energy-momentum requires that
$$
m_0^2 = \frac{m_1^2}{\xi} + \frac{m_2^2}{1-\xi}
$$
I haven't yet used the condition that the masses are small, and I don't see how to use it naturally. In the limit that $m_1 = m_2 = m'$, the conservation law states that
$$
\frac{m_0^2}{m'^2} = \frac{1}{\xi(1-\xi)}
$$
and thus that
$$
\ln \frac{m_0}{m_1} = \ln \frac{m_0}{m_2} = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1}{\xi} + \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1}{1-\xi}
$$
This clearly isn't working - it makes
$$
y_1 - y_0 = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{\xi}{1-\xi} \\
y_2 - y_0 = \frac{1}{2} \ln \frac{1-\xi}{\xi}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. I should have mentioned that the masses are small but $p_{(1,2)\perp}$ are not. So $p_i^- = \frac{p_{i\perp}^2}{2p_i^+}$ for $i=1,2$.

Comment: Ah, okay. At first glance that makes it look like the above still works with $m_1 = m_2 = |p_T|$.